# Stylesheet in Grails Feeds Plugin

Tags: grails, groovy, feed, grails-plugin

trying to include stylesheet in grails plugin, any suggestion in how to implement with plugin or do I just need to write my own feed code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to put the css in the `web-app/css` directory of your grails plug-in.  For an example, you can check out the [Grails UI source](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/grails-plugins/grails-grails-ui) on the fisheye repository which includes some CSS files using this approach.